# Airflow initdb stuck on "add max tries column to task instance"

Tags: airflow

I'm using Airflow with MSSQL 2016 as backend. I started Airflow for the first time, running first Airflow initdb.

It seems to be fine until it get stuck (for more than an hour) on `Running upgrade 127d2bf2dfa7 -> cc1e65623dc7, add max tries column to task instance`.

I'm not sure why does it take so long, as this is the first time I'm running Airflow, thus the DB is empty, and no actual migration should happen...

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [migration file](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/migrations/versions/cc1e65623dc7_add_max_tries_column_to_task_instance.py) you'll see the loop for all dags and tasks. You probably have a lot of them. Just make airflow think there is no dags in the dags folder.

Solution: set environment variable AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER to, for example, `/tmp/123` (any empty directory will work), and run `airflow initdb` again

Comment: This may speedup initdb process but setting AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER will change the dag_folder in airflow.cfg and you will have to set it back again to see your dags

Comment: airflow initdb command is changed in airflow 2.x.x version. New command to initialize db is 'airflow db init'